# Strambling a list of strings in place

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to scramble a word's letters, but i'm struggling to assign an input to a variable without returning an error

```
import random

Word = input("Input the value")

random.shuffle(Word)

print(Word)
```

If i leave the shuffle function in it returns an error saying:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

How do i ask for an input that is assigned *directly to a string* for me to then scramble using this function? This is for Python 3.0 onwards

Comment: There is no list of strings anywhere in your code, contrary to what the title of your question would make us believe.

Comment: Strings are immutable, they cannot be modified in-place.